# I cant get the localStoarge data, i'm using useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, jsx, use-effect

Every Time i try to refresh the page it returns to 0.
I'm taking the bestScore from turns when the match is equal to 6,
so basically everytime the matched cards hit 6 it will take the bestScore from the turns and save the bestScore to localStoarge and it works but when i try to refresh its gone

```
 function App() {
      const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
      const [turns, setTurns] = useState(0);
      const [match, matchedCards] = useState(0);
        const [bestScore, setBestScore] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("highestScoresss")
  );
  const [choiceOne, setChoiceOne] = useState(null); //Kullanici 1.karta basinca setChoiceOne o karti alacak ve guncelliyecek
  const [choiceTwo, setChoiceTwo] = useState(null); //Kullanici 2.karta basinca setChoiceTwo o karti alacak ve guncelliyecek
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (match === 6) {
      const highScore = Math.min(turns, bestScore);
      setBestScore(highScore);
      setBestScore(turns);
    } else {
      console.log("false");
    }
  }, [turns]);
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("highestScoresss", JSON.stringify(bestScore));
  });
```

This Is the JSX

```
<div className="bilgi">
        <p>Sıra: {turns}</p>
        <p>Bulunan: {match}</p>
        <p>En iyi Skor: {bestScore}</p>
        <button onClick={shuffleCards}>Yeni Oyun</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: May I please request that you mention the code snippet in the Description of this question?
Or [Display the image in the Description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Because your first effect runs on every update (including init) it will set localStorage to 0 because this is what you are setting in your useState

Comment: so how can i fix it

Comment: Is there a reason why you enqueue a `setBestScore(highScore);` state update and then immediately overwrite it with an enqueued `setBestScore(turns);` update in the first `useEffect` hook callback?

Comment: Also, please don't *change* the code example in your question *after* people have provided answers against earlier revisions. If you are trying solutions out and run into further issues then please add them as "update" sections so the original code example is maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your implementation is that you set state to `0` ***first***, and then the `useEffect` hook runs and sets localStorage to the state value.

If you are potentially initializing your state to a value stored in localStorage then I suggest using a lazy initialization function so the initial state value is set *before* the initial render and eliminates the need for the additional `useEffect` hook to set state from storage. This reads from localStorage and returns the parsed value, or `0` if the parsed result is null or undefined.

```
const initializeState = () => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("highestScoresss")) ?? 0;
};

...

const [bestScore, setBestScore] = useState(initializeState());
```

You will want to use a dependency array on the `useEffect` that is persisting the "highestScoresss" value in localStorage such that it only triggers when the `bestScore` state value updates and ***not*** on each and every render.

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("highestScoresss", JSON.stringify(bestScore));
}, [bestScore]);
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the Code image, I think that you want that the `bestScore` to be set in the local storage with the key `highestScores`.

Your current useEffect hook implementation lacks a dependency array. You want that the `localStorage` should be updated every time a new `bestScore` is set.
For that add `bestScore` to the dependency array.

```js
useEffect(() => /* YOUR OPERATION*/, [any_dependency])
```

Also, **I recommend that you look at your first useEffect implementation again**. You seem to be setting the `bestScore` state twice. Once with `highScore` and then with `turns`.

### Recommended Reading

- [About Dependency Array - ReactJS Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Comment: Now every time i refresh i'm getting the value between "/2/", like if refresh twice i will get "\"\\\"0\\\"\"" and so on